# Update woocommerce product fields like sku , size, price , name , weight?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to update woocommerce product sku , size, price , name , weight.

I use the code below for some adjustments it works fine. For example on price, but it does not work on name, weight, etc ...

```php
update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_name', "New Product")
update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_name', "New Product");
update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_size', "New Product");
update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_weight', "New Product");
```

Is there an alternative that can change both product attributes and fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post_meta` does not contain `_name`

Use the following function instead: [wp_update_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/)

A example

```php
post_id = $product->get_id();

$my_post = array(
   'ID' =>  $post_id,
   'post_title' => 'my title',
   'post_name' => 'my name',
   'post_status' => 'publish'
);   
wp_update_post( $my_post );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', 1234 );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', 5 );
```

Comment: its working but how to update other product fields like product attributes , Stock quantity .

Comment: you can use update_post_meta() for that, it is best to look in your database which field contains which key and values

Comment: It isn't working I have used the same on size. Do you know any alternate query

Comment: I have updated my answer, make sure you do not insert text if a numeric value is expected and vice versa, 
as I already indicated, look in phpmyadmin which keys and values ​​are already being used